# plotting a mesh (model grid) on the basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, netcdf

I would like to plot my model's grid on a basemap (here a Lambert Conformal projection) so that the code reads the coordinates of each grid point from the netCDF (.nc) file (the .nc file only includes these coordinates) and and connects them rectangularly (it's a C-grid) to eachother by lines and plots them. So far I have plotted these coordinates as dots on the map with "map.scatter"; but it doesn't make any sense to me to have only dots on my map as the model grid!

Here is my written code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from   netCDF4 import Dataset as open_ncfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import numpy as np

#-- open netcdf file
nc = open_ncfile('/desktop/grid.nc')

#-- read variable

lat = nc.variables['grid_corner_lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['grid_corner_lon'][:]

#-- create figure and axes instances
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax  = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.9])

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-25,llcrnrlat=70,urcrnrlon=30,urcrnrlat=80,\
        rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
        resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.,projection='lcc',\
        lat_0=85.,lat_1=75.,lon_0=0.,ax=ax)

map.drawcoastlines()
map.fillcontinents(color='0.90',lake_color='0.90')

# draw parallels and meridians.
map.drawparallels(np.arange(70.,90.,5.),labels=[1,1,0,1],fontsize=10)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,10.),labels=[1,1,0,1],fontsize=10)
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')

x, y = map(lon,lat)

map.scatter(x,y,0.01,marker='.',color='k')

#-- add plot title

plt.show()
```

So, I would appreciate any help or comment :)

Comment: Can you upload your data or link to the grid.nc file? It's rather difficult to picture what's going on without it.

Comment: Did you solve this question. I got exactly the same one.